# Output Custom Fields in Single Post of Single Category

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I've set up a gravity form submission to enable florists to submit their listings, which then creates a post in the "directory" category on my site. I have a number of custom fields set to capture data such as address of TOWN and COUNTY. My question is what code do i need to input into single.php file and where so that these custom fields are only outputted on the page when the post appears in the DIRECTORY category and not on all other posts/categories. Hope that makes sense.
THanks in advance
Mike

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what we need. You can edit your question with details of the exact problem you are having, what you have tried to solve it.

Comment: I added php otput code into the single.php file, but this output to every post page, i do not know how to add code so it only appears on the page when the post is in the single directory category, and not in others....

Comment: might also add I am obviously a complete newbie

Comment: Welcome to the world of WordPress. :) You're ready to look into the template hierarchy to use templates other than single.php to render content other than a standard blog post. https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/. This isn't an answer to How to do this properly. That's a bigger answer. But perhaps this can help you to reformulate your question. HTH